# from plumbum.cmd import git, grep, sed, wc

Tags: python, plumbum

> ImportError: cannot import name 'grep' from 'plumbum.cmd' (unknown
> location)

I tried installing the module in Anaconda using conda install plumbum and it did install. Now what I am missing such that the above import do not work.

I used Spyder editor for this but planning to transition soon to Visual Studio Code if that makes any difference.

Comment: Sounds more like a python library import question than a git question. Are you sure that your editor is using the anaconda environment?

Comment: `plumbum` needs to be able to find those command line tools.  Do you have a set of Unix commands installed?  They may not be in your normal path.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, how do I check that? I am not sure.

Comment: If you didn't install Unix-like tools, then you don't have Unix-like tools.  They don't come with Windows.  What are you really trying to do here?  Most of `grep`, `wc`, and `sed` can be done quite efficiently in Python directly.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have adopted someone else's work and am working on it to add automation tools for git (moving from one repo to another) using Python script (reading the destination, from addresses of the repos from command line etc)

Comment: If you have `git` installed, then the tools you want are in "c:\Program Files\git\usr\bin".  You just need to add that to your PATH before running.

Comment: The tag [tag:git] is not really meant for any Git Python modules, and in any case this has nothing to do with Git at all. The actual problem has to do with setting up Python's import path and/or installing the modules that are to be imported into the places Python is going to look. I don't use Anaconda so I'm not sure what preferences those folks have, but in general, for Python environments, I prefer using virtualenv to encapsulate dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

That error means plumbum was unable to find those commands in your PATH.

Try adding your unix util folder to your PATH.

Or modifying your path before importing from plumbum:

```
os.environ["PATH"] = (
    os.path.expanduser("~/scoop/apps/git/current/usr/bin/") + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
)

from plumbum.cmd import git, grep, sed, wc
```

I installed git on Windows with scoop, so that adds the unix utils that come with git to my PATH.